# Plaid linktoken and expiration are null in live server

Tags: c#, .net, plaid

I tried running this locally, and it works perfectly fine, but on the live server, there's no exception thrown and it returns `linktoken` and exception null.

```
public async Task<CreateLinkTokenResult> GetPlaidLinkToken()
{
    var linkToken = await _client.CreateLinkToken(new CreateLinkTokenRequest()
    {
        ClientId = _clientId,
        Secret = _secret,
        User = new CreateLinkTokenRequest.UserInfo
        {
            ClientUserId = _userContext.CurrentUser.UserId,

        },
        CountryCodes = new[] { "US" },
        ClientName = "TestClient",
        Products = new[] { "transactions" }
    });
    return new CreateLinkTokenResult
    {
        Expiration = linkToken.Expiration,
        LinkToken = linkToken.LinkToken
    };
}
```

```json
{
  "data": {
    "linkToken": null,
    "expiration": null
  },
  "exception": null,
  "errorMessage": "",
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

This is the response I get in the live server:
[image: This is the response I get in the live server]

Answer (score 0):

Very weird. This is a bit of a guess, but have you considered contacting the author of the SDK you're using? I noticed you tagged this with C# and .NET, which have community (unofficial) SDK support. According to our API documentation the `link_token` and `expiration` responses from `/link/token/create` are not nullable, so it should never be possible to get the results you're seeing from the API, which makes me think that potentially the problem could be happening at the SDK layer. Does the issue still happen if you don't use an SDK and just make raw POST requests?

If that doesn't resolve your problem, please feel free to file a Plaid support ticket.

Comment: Haven't tried contacting them yet. But I made some modification on my development setup just to reproduce the issue on my local and I was able to reproduce it by messing with the secret key or clientId of the plaid environment. But it's so weird since my development and live server has the same secret key and clientId, yet it's only working on the localhost.

Comment: Huh. And to clarify both environments are set up to use Development, and you are using a Development secret for both? And you have confirmed on the Plaid developer dashboard that you still have remaining Development Items / haven't used them all up?

Comment: Actually, we're using the Sandbox secret for both.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, the term I used for my local working setup is development setup, I'm not referring to the development environment in plaid. Thank you for answering and helping me thou. Hope you can give me a lead on this one, I'm stuck. :(

Comment: yeah, feel free to reference our Quickstart code for this at https://github.com/plaid/quickstart/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/plaid/quickstart/resources/LinkTokenResource.java#L51 and if that doesn't help you out, go ahead and submit a support ticket.